# How to input information from an external file with tags like in Biblatex?

Tags: tags

Biblatex allows you to write the information about various sources in an abstract way, that is, with tags like `title = "X"`, and then to pull that information into your document, with commands like `\cite` or `\citetitle`.

Is it possible to define a custom external file in a similar way, where specific information is pulled in by its tags?

For example, if I were writing a resume in Latex, the external file could look like:

```
Name = "John Smith"
Address = "Forest Lane"
Phone number = "1-800-ABCD"
```

And then in the document I would simply write:

```
\Huge{\Name}
\normalsize{\Address}
```

Or something similar?

Comment: See the `datatool` package.

Comment: you can use biblatex for this  - the datamodel is extensible. I'm managing my addresses with it.

Comment: Link to Ulrike's article about the address database with `biblatex`: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111fischer.pdf. `datatool` and other CSV solutions have less overhead than `biblatex`, but `biblatex` has some nice goodies that might come in handy for some jobs.